# How is possible to force Qt QMake project to use C++98 standard?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, c++98

I tried this in my `.pro` and it is being ignored:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++98
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
```

Comment: What Qt version's qmake are you trying to do this with? It may not be possible with recent versions to target anything less than C++11

Comment: @Caleth Qt 5.11.0

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to have a cmake project instead. Then you'd have:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(foo)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 98)
```

Qt Creator supports cmake projects, thus there's no advantage to using qmake for such projects anymore. After all, the Qt dependency is specious - it's a dependency on qmake and nothing else, and qmake only comes bundled with Qt's Base module.

For qmake, you have to set the compiler flags directly:

```
!win32-msvc: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++98
```

Theres no way to set it for MSVC, no matter what build tool you're using: it's the limitation of the compiler itself. The only approach is to use a sufficiently old toolset, and optionally override `QMAKE_CXX` with the compiler's name (not path!). The compiler needs to be in the `PATH`, i.e. you'd have to use the toolset's `vsvars` script to set it up.

Comment: I am using MinGW as compiler on Windows, and your line `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++98` looks like it is being ignored.

Comment: Iff you have deleted the build folder and the problem persists, then you should look at the command line of the compiler to determine whether it's being passed that option. If it is, then yes, MinGW will support it, and your expectations of what the option does are broken. What do you think it does, anyway? It's also possible that qmake is passing two conflicting options, and the compiler chooses the latter one. It's possible then to remove that option from its source.